# Develop a cron job script which use laravel

Tags: php, bash, shell, laravel-5.1

I want to run a script which use need to access following from laravel

1. Database
2. Email Templates

But that script must be executed from bash or file cronjob. What would be the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:
[Laravel docs scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about this